# android mediarecorder exception

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

I try to use the MediaRecorder class to record a video but I get an exception : failed to get Camera parameters. Prepare failed.

Here's my code :

```
        camera = Camera.open();
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);
        recorder.setVideoSource(VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(m_holder.getSurface());
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setMaxDuration(10000);
        recorder.setOutputFile(file.getPath());
        recorder.prepare();
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You need unlock camera, try to call

```
camera.unlock();
```

before recorder.setCamera

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing that you didn't include setAudioSource or setFrameRate - sometimes the MediaRecorder is picky about these setups.

Also, I have typically seen the previewDisplay set before the other items.

Do you have a logcat dump for this?

FYI, I have noticed that getting video to work with some devices is tricky - the timing for the MediaRecorder prepare is particular, and sometimes requires extra code for delay.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5050